# Prove or disprove: If $A$ is $n\times n$ and $\exists\;m\in \Bbb{N}:\;A^m=I_n$, then $A$ is invertible.

Tags: matrices, algebra-precalculus, matrix-equations

Is this statement true? If $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix and $A^m=I_n$ for some $m\in \Bbb{N}$, then $A$ is invertible.

**My trial**

Let $n\in \Bbb{N}$ be fixed. Then, $$[\det(A)]^m=\det(A^m)=I_n=1.$$
Hence, $$\det(A)=1\neq 0.$$
Thus, $A$ is invertible since $\det(A)\neq 0.$. I'm I right or is there a counter-example?

Comment: Looks good. Alternatively, $A(A^{m-1})=I=(A^{m-1})A$ so $A^{-1}=A^{m-1}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right conclusion is $\det(A) \ne 0$, hence it is invertible.

Notice that we can't conclude that $\det(A)=1$. After all, it can take value $-1$.

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit!

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.

Answer (score 6):

I think it is easier to see it this way: what is $AA^{m-1} = A^{m-1}A$?

Answer (score 2):

It's invertible since it has a inverse, $A^{m-1}$ that is. By the way, $\det(A)$ could also be -1.